# What will happen to the daily reputation over 200 units?

Tags: support, reputation

Assume, someone's reputation within a day exceeds the threshold 200 units.

What will happen to the rest of it?... Will it be considered for the next day to be applied or it will be lost?

Comment: this may help you http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4473/what-is-the-logic-behind-the-daily-reputation-cap-of-200

Comment: [Also from the main SE meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

Comment: I always thought that they are used to cross-finance the association bonus… Or are donated to users in need…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, upvotes received after you hit the reputation cap will not be applied the next day.

From [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it):

> The maximum amount of reputation you can earn *in one* day from upvotes and approved suggested edits is 200. Any *upvotes* you receive after reaching that number no longer award any points.
>
> You can still earn rep beyond the cap by winning a bounty, accepting an answer, or having one of your answers accepted. Downvotes will also still count against you, but the rep lost can be reclaimed from new upvotes.